# Add custom field to "Additional Information" tab (WooCommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tabs, product

I'm trying to use ACF to add a custom attribute to the "Additional Information" tab for the products in WooCommerce. I want the admin to be able to upload a PDF that then should be set and linked in the table found in the "Additional Information" tab.

I've found the default template for the attributes in the plugin directory for WooCommerce, more precisely `woocommerce/templates/single-product/product-attributes.php`. [This is how the template looks](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/single-product/product-attributes.php). I can easily just put the `the_field("pdf")` there to display the custom field, but the problem I'm running into is that the Additional Information tab will only show if attributes has been added through WooCommerce.

Is there some way to add additional conditional tags for when to display the Additional Information tab? If I somehow could add `if (get_field("pdf"))` to that code, I think this would be solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated:** In Woocommerce if any dimensions, weight or product attributes *(set to be displayed on product)* exist, "Additional Information" tab will be displayed…

So if the tab is hidden and you have added on *`single-product/product-attributes.php`* template a custom field `get_field("pdf")` to be displayed  **that has a value**, you can **force "Additional Information" tab to appear** using:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_customize_tabs', 100, 1 );
function woo_customize_tabs( $tabs ) {
    if( ! isset($tabs['additional_information']) && null !== get_field("pdf") ){
        $tabs['reviews']['priority'] = 30;
        $reviews = $tabs['reviews'];
        unset($tabs['reviews']);
        $tabs['additional_information'] = array(
            'title'     => __( 'Additional information', 'woocommerce' ),
            'priority'  => '20',
            'callback'  => 'woocommerce_product_additional_information_tab',
        );
        $tabs['reviews'] = $reviews;
    }
    return $tabs;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Is there any way to use the `get_field("pdf")` code and get the additional information tab to show if either the dimensions attributes are set OR the "pdf" ACF field is set for a specific product?

Comment: It worked! I had to change `isset(get_field("pdf"))` to `null !== get_field("pdf")` though in order to get rid of an error telling me that `isset` could not be used on `get_field()`. So maybe that should be changed in your answer if that's true. Thank you so much for your help!